# Notice: Undefined index: filter in ...wp-includes/default-widgets.php on line 382

Tags: widgets, errors

I'm getting this message on a WP 3.2.1 install with PHP version 5.2.17

```
Notice: Undefined index: filter in /home/netstewp/public_html/wp-includes/default-widgets.php on line 382
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That a Notice, not an error. Turn off notices in your PHP installation, or turn off the WP_DEBUG mode.

More importantly, turn off display_errors. The display_errors setting should never, ever, be enabled on a production site. That's for debugging only.

Comment: Thanks Otto. The site is not mine. I'm supporting someone who is using my theme. I'm take "note" of the difference between notice and error.